# How do Terran hide SCVs within command centers?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

I've seen terran put scvs into their command center and lift off, how do you put scvs into the command center?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a button on the command center's menu called load SCV's.  Just stand a bunch of SCV's near it and they'll all load in.  (You can do this while flying too)

Comment: You don't even need to move SCV's right next to the command center -- if they're mining from the command center (at a normal distance, mind) they'll still come over and hop in. (I wonder about the range of the "call" now, come to think of it. Is it just 5 nearest, you think?